# Flex Mobile: file.exists issue

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, air, flex4

I am working on a sample mobile app and having issues dealing with File storage.

Below is my code:

```
var dbFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath( "mydb.db");

if(dbFile.exists) //always return false
{
    startConnection();
}
else
{
    trace("File storage issue.");
}
```

It always goes to trace statement.

Below is the debug view for the dbFile object:
[image: File Object debug view]

Any pointer towards solution is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry; what is the problem?  Are you sure that the file is at the location you specified?

Comment: Are you actually creating the file? Just resolving that path with a `File` object does not create the object. You need to open a `FileStream` and use `FileMode.WRITE` (or, maybe, `FileMode.APPEND`) and that will create the file. Before that happens, that file will not exist.

Comment: It's a bit weird. It used to work without using any code to create a file using FileStream object and then it stopped working. And intermittently, it works.